# Fourier transfrom of sin derivation

Tags: fourier-transform

One property of Fourier transform is:
$\frac{d}{dt}f(t) \xrightarrow{\mathscr{F}} (j\omega) F(\omega)$

We know following transform pairs:

$\sin(\omega_0t + \theta) \xrightarrow{\mathscr{F}} j\pi [e^{-j\theta} \delta(\omega + \omega_0) - e^{j \theta} \delta(\omega - \omega_0)]$

$\cos(\omega_0t + \theta) \xrightarrow{\mathscr{F}} \pi [e^{-j\theta} \delta(\omega + \omega_0) + e^{j \theta} \delta(\omega - \omega_0)]$

Now let's take $f(t) = \sin(\omega_0t + \theta)$.

$\frac{d}{dt}f(t) = \omega_0 \cos(\omega_0t + \theta) = f_2(t)$

Now we take fourier transform of $f_2(t)$ and we get

$f_2(t) \xrightarrow{\mathscr{F}} \omega_0 \pi [e^{-j\theta} \delta(\omega + \omega_0) + e^{j \theta} \delta(\omega - \omega_0)]$

Now calculate fourier transform using property:

$\frac{d}{dt}f(t) \xrightarrow{\mathscr{F}} (j \omega) j\pi [e^{-j\theta} \delta(\omega + \omega_0) - e^{j \theta} \delta(\omega - \omega_0)] =
 -\omega \pi [e^{-j\theta} \delta(\omega + \omega_0) - e^{j \theta} \delta(\omega - \omega_0)] $

Why transformations are not equal?

And most importantly why do I get $\omega_0$ in one case and $\omega$ in other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that the distributions $f(x)\delta(x-x')$ and $f(x')\delta (x-x')$ are equivalent.  Therefore,

$$f(x)\delta(x-x')=f(x')\delta(x-x') \tag 1$$

Now, let $f(x)=-x$, $x=\omega$ and $x'=-\omega_0$ in $(1)$.  Then, we have

$$-\omega \delta(\omega+\omega_0)=\omega_0\delta(\omega+\omega_0) \tag 2$$

And then let $f(x)=x$, $x=\omega$ and $x'=\omega_0$.  Then, we have

$$\omega \delta(\omega-\omega_0)=\omega_0\delta(\omega-\omega_0) \tag 3$$

Now, we can easily obtain the questioned equality using $(2)$ and $(3)$.